# Getting "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette." from trying to run ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax-error, data-analysis

Having some error that's preventing me from plotting a PCA plot? Here is my output when I run this set of code on terminal.

```
> #pdf(file="pca.mouse.control.pdf")
> #performing PCA using top 500 varying genes
> pcaData<-plotPCA(logTrans, intgroup=c("condition","time"), ntop=3000,returnData=TRUE) #top 1000
> percentVar<-round(100*attr(pcaData,"percentVar")) #percent variance caused by pca1, pca2 rounded to a percentage
> #coloring the points by Condition and shaping the points by Sex
> ggplot(pcaData, aes(PC1, PC2, color=condition, shape=time))+
+   geom_point(size=3)+
+   xlab(paste0("PC1: ",percentVar[1],
+               "%variance"))+
+   ylab(paste0("PC2: ",percentVar[2],
+               "%variance"))+
+   coord_fixed()
Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.
```

I didn't seem to add a color or ask for a hue palette? I'm very confused where this error is coming from.

I tried modifying with the parentheses, and they didn't help me at all. Maybe it is parentheses but I'm not getting them right at the moment. Need some help.

EDIT:
logTrans context

```
> dput(sampleTable)
structure(list(trash = c("024_S113.gff", "067_S146.gff", "076_S154.gff", 
"084_S160.gff", "093_S168.gff", "104_S178.gff", "111_S185.gff", 
"012_S103.gff", "029_S118.gff", "050_S134.gff", "052_S135.gff", 
"083_S159.gff", "086_S162.gff", "005_S99.gff", "013_S104.gff", 
"057_S139.gff", "061_S142.gff", "064_S144.gff", "071_S149.gff", 
"098_S172.gff", "117_S190.gff", "014_S105.gff", "023_S112.gff", 
"027_S116.gff", "037_S125.gff", "045_S131.gff", "046_S132.gff", 
"088_S164.gff", "090_S166.gff", "070_S148.gff", "081_S157.gff", 
"082_S158.gff", "087_S163.gff", "105_S179.gff", "010_S102.gff", 
"020_S109.gff", "021_S110.gff", "034_S122.gff", "036_S124.gff", 
"068_S147.gff", "073_S151.gff", "074_S152.gff", "110_S184.gff", 
"022_S111.gff", "031_S120.gff", "035_S123.gff", "049_S133.gff", 
"072_S150.gff", "085_S161.gff", "089_S165.gff", "099_S173.gff", 
"101_S175.gff", "015_S106.gff", "026_S115.gff", "053_S136.gff", 
"065_S145.gff", "096_S170.gff", "109_S183.gff", "118_S191.gff", 
"001_S96.gff", "004_S98.gff", "007_S100.gff", "017_S107.gff", 
"028_S117.gff", "059_S141.gff", "078_S155.gff", "103_S177.gff", 
"106_S180.gff", "115_S188.gff", "002_S97.gff", "041_S128.gff", 
"063_S143.gff", "075_S153.gff", "080_S156.gff", "095_S169.gff", 
"102_S176.gff", "107_S181.gff", "114_S187.gff", "008_S101.gff", 
"019_S108.gff", "032_S121.gff", "038_S126.gff", "040_S127.gff", 
"091_S167.gff", "097_S171.gff", "100_S174.gff", "025_S114.gff", 
"030_S119.gff", "042_S129.gff", "044_S130.gff", "055_S137.gff", 
"056_S138.gff", "058_S140.gff", "108_S182.gff", "113_S186.gff", 
"116_S189.gff", "119_S192.gff", "121_S193.gff", "122_S194.gff", 
"124_S195.gff", "125_S196.gff", "126_S197.gff", "127_S198.gff", 
"128_S199.gff", "129_S200.gff", "130_S201.gff", "131_S202.gff", 
"132_S203.gff", "039_S211.gff", "043_S212.gff", "120_S213.gff", 
"123_S214.gff", "018_S204.gff", "033_S205.gff", "051_S206.gff", 
"062_S207.gff", "066_S208.gff", "077_S209.gff", "094_S210.gff"
), filename = c("A-000h-024_S113.gff", "A-000h-067_S146.gff", 
"A-000h-076_S154.gff", "A-000h-084_S160.gff", "A-000h-093_S168.gff", 
"A-000h-104_S178.gff", "A-000h-111_S185.gff", "A-072h-012_S103.gff", 
"A-072h-029_S118.gff", "A-072h-050_S134.gff", "A-072h-052_S135.gff", 
"A-072h-083_S159.gff", "A-072h-086_S162.gff", "A-168h-005_S99.gff", 
"A-168h-013_S104.gff", "A-168h-057_S139.gff", "A-168h-061_S142.gff", 
"A-168h-064_S144.gff", "A-168h-071_S149.gff", "A-168h-098_S172.gff", 
"A-168h-117_S190.gff", "B-000h-014_S105.gff", "B-000h-023_S112.gff", 
"B-000h-027_S116.gff", "B-000h-037_S125.gff", "B-000h-045_S131.gff", 
"B-000h-046_S132.gff", "B-000h-088_S164.gff", "B-000h-090_S166.gff", 
"B-072h-070_S148.gff", "B-072h-081_S157.gff", "B-072h-082_S158.gff", 
"B-072h-087_S163.gff", "B-072h-105_S179.gff", "B-168h-010_S102.gff", 
"B-168h-020_S109.gff", "B-168h-021_S110.gff", "B-168h-034_S122.gff", 
"B-168h-036_S124.gff", "B-168h-068_S147.gff", "B-168h-073_S151.gff", 
"B-168h-074_S152.gff", "B-168h-110_S184.gff", "C-000h-022_S111.gff", 
"C-000h-031_S120.gff", "C-000h-035_S123.gff", "C-000h-049_S133.gff", 
"C-000h-072_S150.gff", "C-000h-085_S161.gff", "C-000h-089_S165.gff", 
"C-000h-099_S173.gff", "C-000h-101_S175.gff", "C-072h-015_S106.gff", 
"C-072h-026_S115.gff", "C-072h-053_S136.gff", "C-072h-065_S145.gff", 
"C-072h-096_S170.gff", "C-072h-109_S183.gff", "C-072h-118_S191.gff", 
"C-168h-001_S96.gff", "C-168h-004_S98.gff", "C-168h-007_S100.gff", 
"C-168h-017_S107.gff", "C-168h-028_S117.gff", "C-168h-059_S141.gff", 
"C-168h-078_S155.gff", "C-168h-103_S177.gff", "C-168h-106_S180.gff", 
"C-168h-115_S188.gff", "D-000h-002_S97.gff", "D-000h-041_S128.gff", 
"D-000h-063_S143.gff", "D-000h-075_S153.gff", "D-000h-080_S156.gff", 
"D-000h-095_S169.gff", "D-000h-102_S176.gff", "D-000h-107_S181.gff", 
"D-000h-114_S187.gff", "D-072h-008_S101.gff", "D-072h-019_S108.gff", 
"D-072h-032_S121.gff", "D-072h-038_S126.gff", "D-072h-040_S127.gff", 
"D-072h-091_S167.gff", "D-072h-097_S171.gff", "D-072h-100_S174.gff", 
"D-168h-025_S114.gff", "D-168h-030_S119.gff", "D-168h-042_S129.gff", 
"D-168h-044_S130.gff", "D-168h-055_S137.gff", "D-168h-056_S138.gff", 
"D-168h-058_S140.gff", "D-168h-108_S182.gff", "D-168h-113_S186.gff", 
"D-168h-116_S189.gff", "N-000h-119_S192.gff", "N-000h-121_S193.gff", 
"N-000h-122_S194.gff", "N-000h-124_S195.gff", "N-000h-125_S196.gff", 
"N-000h-126_S197.gff", "N-000h-127_S198.gff", "N-000h-128_S199.gff", 
"N-000h-129_S200.gff", "N-000h-130_S201.gff", "N-000h-131_S202.gff", 
"N-000h-132_S203.gff", "X-000h-039_S211.gff", "X-000h-043_S212.gff", 
"X-000h-120_S213.gff", "X-000h-123_S214.gff", "X-072h-018_S204.gff", 
"X-072h-033_S205.gff", "X-072h-051_S206.gff", "X-072h-062_S207.gff", 
"X-072h-066_S208.gff", "X-072h-077_S209.gff", "X-072h-094_S210.gff"
), treatment_group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), time = c("000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "072h", "072h", "072h", 
"072h", "072h", "072h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", 
"168h", "168h", "168h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "000h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", 
"168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", 
"168h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", 
"072h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", 
"168h", "168h", "168h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", 
"072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", 
"168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "168h", "000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", 
"000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "000h", "072h", "072h", 
"072h", "072h", "072h", "072h", "072h")), row.names = c(NA, -119L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



    ddsHTSeq<-DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(sampleTable=sampleTable, directory=directory, design=~treatment_group+time) 
    ddsHTSeq<- estimateSizeFactors(ddsHTSeq)
    logTrans<- vst(ddsHTSeq) #normalized counts
```

dput(pcaData)

```
> pcaData
                          PC1        PC2   group condition time            name
A-000h-024_S113  -0.320694178  2.7778412 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-024_S113
A-000h-067_S146  -0.002410985  8.3898396 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-067_S146
A-000h-076_S154   0.499607961  3.7851280 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-076_S154
A-000h-084_S160   2.067338462  3.3101123 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-084_S160
A-000h-093_S168   3.111691815  1.7002517 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-093_S168
A-000h-104_S178  -3.818532232  1.1508051 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-104_S178
A-000h-111_S185  -3.742749898  3.5110641 NA:000h      <NA> 000h A-000h-111_S185
A-072h-012_S103  -0.534166142  1.8638765 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-012_S103
A-072h-029_S118  -0.836948039  0.2941960 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-029_S118
A-072h-050_S134   2.960265751 -0.6157736 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-050_S134
A-072h-052_S135   3.525457747 -2.4132327 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-052_S135
A-072h-083_S159   2.409759291 -0.1038610 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-083_S159
A-072h-086_S162   3.722458157  5.0023295 NA:072h      <NA> 072h A-072h-086_S162
A-168h-005_S99    2.146962939 -0.0394367 NA:168h      <NA> 168h  A-168h-005_S99
A-168h-013_S104   2.460944560 -2.6037950 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-013_S104
A-168h-057_S139   0.726681360  0.3563937 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-057_S139
A-168h-061_S142   3.054806788 -2.7197222 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-061_S142
A-168h-064_S144   2.848271362 -1.8982479 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-064_S144
A-168h-071_S149   1.305806698 -2.6754773 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-071_S149
A-168h-098_S172   2.567909657 -0.8122940 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-098_S172
A-168h-117_S190  -8.141619722 -2.5115206 NA:168h      <NA> 168h A-168h-117_S190
B-000h-014_S105   2.370623844  2.5494356 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-014_S105
B-000h-023_S112   0.658832442  3.3414638 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-023_S112
B-000h-027_S116  -0.869408244  2.7761878 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-027_S116
B-000h-037_S125   6.529922314  1.8519230 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-037_S125
B-000h-045_S131   3.880650507  4.0539278 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-045_S131
B-000h-046_S132   2.862712194  3.9337226 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-046_S132
B-000h-088_S164   1.847039948  6.1028658 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-088_S164
B-000h-090_S166   0.849799101  2.5122905 NA:000h      <NA> 000h B-000h-090_S166
B-072h-070_S148   0.359739401 -1.7607710 NA:072h      <NA> 072h B-072h-070_S148
B-072h-081_S157   1.099741212 -0.5528003 NA:072h      <NA> 072h B-072h-081_S157
B-072h-082_S158  -1.149739682  3.5483062 NA:072h      <NA> 072h B-072h-082_S158
B-072h-087_S163   2.474424568  3.3227377 NA:072h      <NA> 072h B-072h-087_S163
B-072h-105_S179  -4.870152140  4.2411364 NA:072h      <NA> 072h B-072h-105_S179
B-168h-010_S102   1.622330196 -2.3225392 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-010_S102
B-168h-020_S109   0.443072770 -1.9743801 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-020_S109
B-168h-021_S110   0.605650856 -1.8533296 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-021_S110
B-168h-034_S122   3.793121081 -0.4871453 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-034_S122
B-168h-036_S124   2.284190679 -1.0805896 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-036_S124
B-168h-068_S147   1.466100677  0.2844068 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-068_S147
B-168h-073_S151   1.542207973 -2.3339288 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-073_S151
B-168h-074_S152   3.269648176  0.1098486 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-074_S152
B-168h-110_S184  -4.812980315 -1.7470181 NA:168h      <NA> 168h B-168h-110_S184
C-000h-022_S111   0.421081990 -1.5410538 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-022_S111
C-000h-031_S120   1.924790839 -1.0966968 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-031_S120
C-000h-035_S123   5.767409891  5.6004148 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-035_S123
C-000h-049_S133   2.698040920 -2.0511850 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-049_S133
C-000h-072_S150   0.153482258 -1.8688691 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-072_S150
C-000h-085_S161   3.974074066 -1.5456674 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-085_S161
C-000h-089_S165   0.895956414 -4.6147697 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-089_S165
C-000h-099_S173   1.403521355 -1.2112024 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-099_S173
C-000h-101_S175   1.120086666 -1.3397290 NA:000h      <NA> 000h C-000h-101_S175
C-072h-015_S106   3.042787752  2.7031248 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-015_S106
C-072h-026_S115   2.986361551  1.2819011 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-026_S115
C-072h-053_S136   2.612581837 -3.0030911 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-053_S136
C-072h-065_S145   5.337826050 -1.4428190 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-065_S145
C-072h-096_S170   0.900925163  0.8642273 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-096_S170
C-072h-109_S183  -5.334425078 -2.4136414 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-109_S183
C-072h-118_S191  -7.231001196  3.2579731 NA:072h      <NA> 072h C-072h-118_S191
C-168h-001_S96    3.023570539 -0.7010362 NA:168h      <NA> 168h  C-168h-001_S96
C-168h-004_S98    1.823423831 -1.7113056 NA:168h      <NA> 168h  C-168h-004_S98
C-168h-007_S100   0.962411992 -2.2924658 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-007_S100
C-168h-017_S107   1.065361860  3.0621013 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-017_S107
C-168h-028_S117  -0.366006851 -2.9235285 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-028_S117
C-168h-059_S141   1.428278165 -1.9400322 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-059_S141
C-168h-078_S155   0.815843404  2.1067205 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-078_S155
C-168h-103_S177  -1.143954264  1.7431866 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-103_S177
C-168h-106_S180  -6.143535335 -2.2050061 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-106_S180
C-168h-115_S188 -10.687616920  0.8673982 NA:168h      <NA> 168h C-168h-115_S188
D-000h-002_S97    1.713323672 -1.8416271 NA:000h      <NA> 000h  D-000h-002_S97
D-000h-041_S128   3.324591638 -2.2369055 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-041_S128
D-000h-063_S143   2.509382117 -2.0362103 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-063_S143
D-000h-075_S153   2.748652742 -3.7119225 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-075_S153
D-000h-080_S156   2.282400058 -2.6198194 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-080_S156
D-000h-095_S169   2.144568051 -2.0766734 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-095_S169
D-000h-102_S176  -1.311142185 -2.3878073 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-102_S176
D-000h-107_S181  -5.927155889 -2.1570771 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-107_S181
D-000h-114_S187  -3.340403022 -0.8760670 NA:000h      <NA> 000h D-000h-114_S187
D-072h-008_S101   2.241312455 -1.5338208 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-008_S101
D-072h-019_S108   1.645271817 -0.5504861 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-019_S108
D-072h-032_S121   4.718969159 -1.1478291 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-032_S121
D-072h-038_S126   3.978578789 -1.2264232 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-038_S126
D-072h-040_S127   3.871264202 -0.6495841 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-040_S127
D-072h-091_S167   1.679631907  0.6100731 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-091_S167
D-072h-097_S171   1.934509572  4.2551949 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-097_S171
D-072h-100_S174  -2.205379764  3.1915375 NA:072h      <NA> 072h D-072h-100_S174
D-168h-025_S114   1.371362706 -1.7243487 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-025_S114
D-168h-030_S119  -1.341233490 -2.0945257 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-030_S119
D-168h-042_S129   2.172584323 -2.4828478 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-042_S129
D-168h-044_S130   1.258171332 -1.9402257 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-044_S130
D-168h-055_S137   3.962113103 -0.4879615 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-055_S137
D-168h-056_S138   0.901000865  1.1711941 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-056_S138
D-168h-058_S140   2.414236421 -0.0441272 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-058_S140
D-168h-108_S182  -5.604362515 -1.0181219 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-108_S182
D-168h-113_S186  -6.850762875 -1.1256681 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-113_S186
D-168h-116_S189  -8.408673481 -0.8937453 NA:168h      <NA> 168h D-168h-116_S189
N-000h-119_S192  -0.003130916  1.3419868 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-119_S192
N-000h-121_S193  -0.103201056 -2.0279611 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-121_S193
N-000h-122_S194  -1.950250818 -0.7800179 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-122_S194
N-000h-124_S195   0.045145274 -1.7753548 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-124_S195
N-000h-125_S196  -0.176879963 -2.2177693 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-125_S196
N-000h-126_S197  -0.624386897 -1.3394352 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-126_S197
N-000h-127_S198  -1.893840840 -0.5811596 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-127_S198
N-000h-128_S199  -0.459150758 -0.6233492 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-128_S199
N-000h-129_S200  -4.304056142 -0.5741117 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-129_S200
N-000h-130_S201  -3.652964941 -2.9512770 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-130_S201
N-000h-131_S202  -7.494324473 -1.6510467 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-131_S202
N-000h-132_S203  -4.586636098 -1.6417175 NA:000h      <NA> 000h N-000h-132_S203
X-000h-039_S211  -1.598262248  0.4686062 NA:000h      <NA> 000h X-000h-039_S211
X-000h-043_S212  -4.110502622  5.5563299 NA:000h      <NA> 000h X-000h-043_S212
X-000h-120_S213  -2.662484813 -2.2099994 NA:000h      <NA> 000h X-000h-120_S213
X-000h-123_S214  -3.526951600  5.0218529 NA:000h      <NA> 000h X-000h-123_S214
X-072h-018_S204  -4.928491326 -1.2340832 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-018_S204
X-072h-033_S205  -5.692045983 -0.5669768 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-033_S205
X-072h-051_S206  -7.672251061  0.2607200 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-051_S206
X-072h-062_S207  -6.029460116  1.7019388 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-062_S207
X-072h-066_S208  -1.350411695  2.0435592 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-066_S208
X-072h-077_S209  -1.086626889  2.2381641 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-077_S209
X-072h-094_S210  -1.741291539  1.3277506 NA:072h      <NA> 072h X-072h-094_S210
```

Comment: Your data does not seem to have a column called `condition`. Perhaps you mean `treatment_group`?

Comment: The first two lines regarding pcaData and percentVar worked fine. percentVar prints out "16 8".

Answer (score 0):

When you showed your PCA, your condition column is full of NAs. I believe you may have nominal values for "condition", which are not supported by PCA (PCA is done only on numerical data). You have ways of dealing with them. You can, for example, create dummy variables.
[I'll link you a website that talks about this.](https://statisticsglobe.com/pca-categorical-variables)

Comment: You would be correct. PCAdata has a NA column in "conditions". Any ideas for fixing it?

Comment: I have attached a dput(PCAdata) for reference.

Comment: @scurry200 I've edited my answer. Please check if it's accurate with your data-set